# How to generate LaTeX file without preamble in R markdown?

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown

I have a LaTeX document that is split to multiple *.tex* files.

I'm using R markdown to generate figures and tables.

Is it possible to generate .tex file from .Rmd without preamble, so that I will be able to just use output in my document? Currently, I need to manually copy part of the output to my .tex file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's suppose your child document is named `child.Rmd` and has the following contents.

````
```{r pressure, echo=FALSE, dev='pdf'}
plot(pressure)
```
````

Run

```
knitr::knit("child.Rmd")
```

and you get `figure/pressure-1.pdf` and `child.md`. Then run

```
rmarkdown::pandoc_convert("child.md", to = "latex", output = "child.tex")
```

Resulting `child.tex` file only contains `\begin{figure} ~~ \end{figure}` block inside. I hope this is the desired result.

If you don't have a strong reason to use RMarkdown, I'd recommend R Sweave; knitr supports [child documents](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/child/)

**UPDATE** You didn't have to remove YAML header from your Rmd file; the above `knitr::knit` and `rmarkdown::pandoc_convert` combination ignores the YAML header. Take a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/kenjisato/3a88e24f3823c9b9a7da494aad24b64b). Run `run_this.R` script and `child.Rmd` will be converted to `child.tex`.  You can of course render this Rmd file to html normally.

Comment: Well, to be honest, I thought that R Markdown is de facto standard. What are the syntax differences between R Sweave and R Markdown?

Comment: R Sweave is LaTeX with R codes. while RMarkdown is Markdown with R. In an Rnw file, codes are surrounded between <<>>= and @, not by those back ticks. I guess Rmarkdown is more popular because not many people want to see a buch of backslashes and braces...

Comment: Okay, but R markdown allows me to create output in different formats (LaTeX/PDF, ODT, DOC, HTML). If R Sweave is LaTeX with R, I guess it can output only LaTeX?

Comment: Ahh, are you going to use your Rmd file (maybe a section of your full paper?) to produce a separate document for a web page or something? Yeah, it makes sense to use Rmarkdown then. I was assuming that you use Rmarkdown solely for the purpose of producing figures and tables, used in LaTeX documents! In any case, you can use `knitr::knit` and `rmarkdown::pandoc_convert` combination I suppose.

Comment: Thanks for detailed response!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by creating a template containing just as much as you want.  Instructions for templates are here:  http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_document_templates.html

You could also look at `bookdown`, which by design is for documents with
many chapters.