# How to convert Rmarkdown file to working latex file

Tags: latex, r-markdown, pandoc

I have written a manuscript I would like to submit to a journal in Rmarkdown. The journal accepts word and latex files, so I am looking for a way to generate a working `.tex` file out of my `.Rmd` file.

I have read some posts that allude to this being possible (e.g., [How to generate LaTeX file without preamble in R markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42876148/how-to-generate-latex-file-without-preamble-in-r-markdown)) and this is getting me some of the way, but I am still having problems.

For example, using the method mentioned in the post above, I can convert a test `.Rmd` into something with a `.tex` filetype. This is the test Rmarkdown (just the usual template for new files):

````
---
title: "Test document"
author: "Me"
date: "23 7 2020"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

This compiles fine to PDF as it should. Then, in the console I run:

```
knitr::knit("test.Rmd")
```

to get a markdown file `test.md` in my working directory, and then I can apparently convert this `.md` file to `.tex` with

```
rmarkdown::pandoc_convert("test.md", to = "latex", output = "test.tex")
```

This produces a `.tex` file that, when I double click on it, pops up a PDF view of the file that looks fine. Taking a look at the file though, it is incomplete or at least unfamiliar to me:

```
\hypertarget{r-markdown}{%
\subsection{R Markdown}\label{r-markdown}}

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax
for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on
using R Markdown see \url{http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com}.

When you click the \textbf{Knit} button a document will be generated
that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code
chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

\begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighting}[]
\KeywordTok{summary}\NormalTok{(cars)}
\end{Highlighting}
\end{Shaded}

\begin{verbatim}
##      speed           dist       
##  Min.   : 4.0   Min.   :  2.00  
##  1st Qu.:12.0   1st Qu.: 26.00  
##  Median :15.0   Median : 36.00  
##  Mean   :15.4   Mean   : 42.98  
##  3rd Qu.:19.0   3rd Qu.: 56.00  
##  Max.   :25.0   Max.   :120.00
\end{verbatim}

\hypertarget{including-plots}{%
\subsection{Including Plots}\label{including-plots}}

You can also embed plots, for example:

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{figure/pressure-1.png}
\caption{plot of chunk pressure}
\end{figure}

Note that the \texttt{echo\ =\ FALSE} parameter was added to the code
chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
```

As far as I can tell, it is missing the preamble, `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}`, and I have no idea what is going on with `hypertarget` bit of the section headers. Unsurprisingly, it does not "re-compile" when I hit run in MiKTeX. The `verbatim` bits for the code chunks look to be what I'm after, though.

So, is there a way to generate a `.tex` file that compiles out of an `.Rmd` file? Or will I have to manually write the preamble and all that? If the answer to my problem is "read up pandoc", then fair enough, I will have to bite the bullet and finally have a look at it. But I find it hard to imagine that there is no good (easy) way to prepare submittable manuscripts in Rmarkdown.

Comment: Use the `pdf_document` option `keep_tex` to keep the full LaTeX source for your document.  It may include more in the preamble than you really want; you can use the `template` option to specify a simpler one.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful to know as well!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pandoc generates LaTeX snippets by default, i.e., not a full document. This can be changed by calling pandoc with the `--standalone` option:

```r
rmarkdown::pandoc_convert(
  "test.md",
  to = "latex",
  output = "out.tex",
  options = "--standalone"
)
```

You can let R do the work and shorten your commands to

```r
render("test.Rmd", output_format = "latex_document")
```

A project of interest might be [rticles](https://github.com/rstudio/rticles).

Comment: Wow, thank you, that seems to work great! I am aware of rticles and have played around with some of the templates before, but maybe I am missing the point of the templates? In my experience, one submits a fairly stripped down word or latex file that conforms with the journal requirements, and if the manuscript is accepted, someone  at the journal takes care of the final layout. Is there a benefit to submitting an article in the final layout style of the journal?

Comment: I think this might differ from journal to journal. One advantage of rticles is that it makes it easy to set the necessary metadata information.